# Как выбрать каждое второе слово из списка?

Tags: python

Вот например список:
`a = ['text', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']`
Вывод должен выглядеть примерно таким образом:
text2
text4

Comment: использовать остаток от деления индекса массива на 2. Т.е. результат будет 0,1,0,1 и т.д.. Вам нужен результат 1 :-). Ну а если у вас просто строка, то сделать из нее массив, используя разделитель запятую

Comment: @dubok79 Как я могу это сделать? Я просто не очень шарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй срезы:
`i = a[1::2]`

i будет равно `['text2', 'text4']`

Можешь почитать про них на этом сайте: https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

Comment: выходит ошибка ```can only concatenate str (not "list") to str```

Comment: @user530445 уверен, что ошибка именно там? У меня всё работает...

Comment: А, извиняюсь я сам с кодом накосячил, щас починил всё работает